# Comparing parameter of a model under two conditions

Tags: modeling

I have a model for  gene expression at two conditions. I estimated parameters for he full model at two conditions based on time course data that I have. Now,  I plan to test if estimated parameters at two conditions are significantly different. I am wondering if I can do it as follows:
add Gaussian noise to my data at two conditions and estimate parameters and repeat it if for example 100 times, then I will have a set of data for parameter at each  condition separately. Finally by using t-test I can say if the parameter has significantly changed? Thank you in advance for your guidance